# How do I change the activity after animation ends? Animation listener doesnt seem to be working

Tags: android, animation

I want to start an animation as soon as the activity is launched. And as soon as the animation ends, I want to start another activity.So I searched a lot and everyone recommended to use onAnimationEnd(). However, on running the code, no new activity is displayed after the animation ends. Can someone point out my error?

**Here is my MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {
TextView ticTacToe;
Animation animation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ticTacToe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tictactoe);
    //bounce is the xml animation file
    animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.bounce);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus)
        ticTacToe.startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
}
```

Comment: is your start animation is working ?

Comment: Yes. It is working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `onWindowFocusChanged`, because your animation starts when your current window get focus but the listener is still not attached to your `animation`

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        }
    }    

    ticTacToe.startAnimation(animation)
```

Or you can also do this in `oncreate`

`animation.setAnimationListener(this);`